# Mysql connection with PHP giving 500 error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php file where I am opening my database connection.

```
$con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '12345' );
if ( ! $con ) {
   die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
} else {
   echo 'Connection established';
}
```

But when running the file I am getting the following error:

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

But if I just try `phpinfo();` in the same file without having the above connection string it runs fine, which means my apache server is running already. I still tried by restarting but no luck!

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

I also tried the same code using `mysqli` but that didn't work either!

```
$con = mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '12345' );
```

I can connect `mysql` from my terminal using the same above credential:

```
$ mysql -u root p
$ password: 12345

mysql>
```

What I am missing?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions were deprecated quite some time ago, you're probably using a version of PHP that doesn't have them. Use PDO instead.

Comment: I am using PHP 7, and hence tried `mysqli` as well. But that didn;t work either! Mentioned in OP.

Comment: Turn on PHP errors to see the errors rather than the 500.

Comment: Maybe, you are missing the port number. Something like this `localhost:8080`

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.** IF you're having problems with Mysqli, show **that** code.

Comment: If you show the actual error somebody might be able to help you.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: `mysqli()` is not a function. See [this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) for some good examples.

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
$con = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '12345' );
if ( ! $con ) {
   die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con) );
} else {
   echo 'Connection established';
}
```